# CrystalDecisions missing

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I have a project that references `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine` but I get a message that the reference can't be found. I've installed:

- Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET 64bit (13.0.22.2668)
- Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework 4 (13.0.1.220)
- Crystal Reports, version for Visual Studio (13.0.22.2668)

My webconfig references a lot of the Crystal assemblies too. Small sample below. I've tried messing with the version numbers but it doesn't seem to change anything.

```
<assemblies>
        <!-- old version 13.0.2000.0 -->
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
and lots more like this.
```

Not sure why the versions are different, I just downloaded the CR Runtimes installer from SAP. I'm using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017 Pro.

I noticed that there is no `References` folder in my project and even when I manually add the CR references, nothing seems to change in the directory and I'm still missing the dependencies.

I have also tried the Crystal Reports nuget package but I still get compliation errors relating to missing Crystal assemblies.

Interestingly, it's also complaining about `System.Data.Linq` not being referenced (I have added the reference) but has succesfully found `System.Data`, `System.Data.SqlClient`, `System.Configuration`, `System.Web`, etc.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Missing references]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had trouble with this scenario, my problem was having Visual Studio 17 and also multiple versions of Crystal Reports / Connectors.

Try with Visual Studio 2013. Community edition should allow you a trial version to check it on a demo environment. Let me know how it works for you.